# In the 3rd game when Eva calls Hideyoshi as a witness, what's the point if there's no red truth?

Tags: umineko-when-they-cry

In the anime (episode 18, part of the 3rd arc of the anime which corresponds to the 3rd episode of the VN [Banquet of the Golden Witch](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Banquet_of_the_Golden_Witch)):

Hideyoshi is called as a witness and says

> I spent the whole time taking care of Eva in our room because she was sick. Of course, Eva didn't leave the room.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's a good idea (both as a tactic from the witch side and in writing a story) to call a 'witness' from the dead, but what's the point if there's no red truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [VN/manga](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Banquet_of_the_Golden_Witch/Colored_Text), there's a red truth: (I edited to emphasise the red part.)

> Battler: Don't try to trick me! Your true form isn't a witch or anything like it, but a flesh and blood human. The human culprit, Ushiromiya Eva!!!
>
> EVA Beatrice summons Hideyoshi as a witness to testify for her
>
> Hideyoshi: I was taking care of Eva in our room the whole time. Of course, Eva didn't leave the room.
>
> Battler: I demand that he repeats it again in red!!
>
> Hideyoshi (in red): **I was in the room the whole time. Both before and after the time of the crime**
>
> Battler (repetition request): 'Aunt Eva was also in the room for the entire time before and after the crime'
>
> Battler: Uncle Hideyoshi was just there to create an alibi. You made him stay in the room and stealthily snuck out.
>
> EVA Beatrice refuses
>
> Battler: Maybe Uncle Hideyoshi didn't leave the room the whole time. But saying he was taking care of you the whole time...is a bright-red lie! Therefore, no alibi exists for you!! You had a chance to slip out of the room and kill Aunt Rosa and Maria! If you think you can dodge that, try proclaiming in red that 'Aunt Eva didn't take a step outside of her room'!! You can't, right?
>
> The witch side resigns

But anyway, I guess it's not really a big deal. Of course you don't trust anything that's not in red.

(

Then again I guess the idea is that

> there's a lot of white text that the witches have gotten past

Battler.

)

---

Btw in the VN:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So yeah obvious not really a big deal.